# Wordpress export-import tables mess up categories

Tags: mysql, wordpress, import

I have multiple wordpress sites that I use the same posts with. So basically I update 1 main site and to update the others I just export from phpmyadmin the tables:

- wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy

After that I empty the same tables from the wordpress site I'd like to update and import the sql file.

Usually that used to work fine until recently I'd start getting the categories messed up.
When I enter the categories page I only see the parent categories shown up with the subcategories.
The strange thing is that I go to posts and I see available posts with subcategories. 
The database looks fine regarding parents numbering. 
Im sure there is no code problem because if I import my backup 5 tables it shows the subcategories well...

Any Idea's?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem (imported all 3 terms tables via MySQL, sub-categories *there* in the database and via other pages but not showing up on Categories page), and it seems like a bug in Wordpress.

I just added a new sub-category as a test, and suddenly all my other sub-categories showed up in the list.

Comment: This worked for me 2020/02/28. I just added a new cat and they all showed up and started to work other places where queried.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you might be to use FeedWordPress or a similar plugin to automatically pull content from the source site to the other sites via RSS. It gives you lots of control over categories, tags, custom fields, and so on, plus it gives you the option of whether to update matching existing posts.

I'm having the same problem you are, but so far FeedWordPress et al won't help because they don't handle custom fields in custom post types, which is what I need.